# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 al usar split() en java

Tags: java

Con motivo de redondear un número hacia arriba o hacia abajo en función de los decimales, he creado un pequeño método en java. El problema que me encuentro es que justo la línea después de aplicar `split()` me devuelve el error `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0`.

Dejo un ejemplo:

```
double descuento_pais = 59.5;                                       
double descuento_pais_final = damedescuento(descuento_pais);

public double damedescuento (double descuento) {

        String descuento_string = String.valueOf(descuento);
        String[] parts = descuento_string.split(".");
        String entero = parts[0]; 
        String decimal = parts[1]; 
        double descuento_pais;

        if (Double.parseDouble(decimal) >= 0.5) {
            descuento_pais = Double.parseDouble(entero) + 1;
        } else {
            descuento_pais = Double.parseDouble(entero);
        }

        return descuento_pais;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que [`String.split(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) espera que le suministres una expresión regular. Y el punto tiene significado especial en regex.

Para que interprete el punto literalmente, debes escaparlo con `\\`:

```
String[] parts = descuento_string.split("\\.");
```

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! Valido la respuesta cuando me deje hacerlo.